# Injecting Handlers in Custom Widget

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin, gwtp

I have a handler classes, I need to inject it in the custom widgets.

I tried the bind() method in ClientModule class, but it is not getting injected.

What am I supposed to do, do get the class injected.

```
public class ExtendedTextBoxBase extends TextBox {

    public ExtendedTextBoxBase() {

        super.addBlurHandler(textBoxBlurHandler);

    }

    @Inject
    TextBoxBlurHandler textBoxBlurHandler; /* custom handler */

}
```

custom handler:

```
public class TextBoxBlurHandler implements BlurHandler {

    @Inject
    public TextBoxBlurHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: provide some sample code to work please.

Comment: Some code would greatly help here

Comment: please find the update with code.

Answer (score 0):

Initial reaction: did you include and @Inject statement in the method (likely constructor) where you would like to inject the handler?

If yes: could you be more specific with some code snippets?

Comment: you mean, adding Inject annotation in the handlers construstor? Yes did... and tried adding Inject private HandlerClass handlerclass; this doesn't work. I tried bind(HandlerClass.class).to(HandlerClass.class); this will not work because its referring to same type. If possible, please show me how to inject a simple class using gin in other class. Not in View or Presenter.

Answer (score 0):

I see two potential errors:

**1. You have code in constructor:**

```
 super.addBlurHandler(textBoxBlurHandler);
```

so you should inject handler by constructor not by field. 
Gin first crate object than inject fields into class, so your handler textBoxBlurHandler is null.

**2. You crate your ExtendedTextBoxBase by uibinder.** If yes, you should add annotation uiField provided=true, and inject this field:

```
@Inject

@UiField(provided=true)

ExtendedTextBoxBase extendedTextBoxBase;
```